# Checking "liveness" of a Windows application?

Tags: python, windows, winapi, pywin32

I've got a Windows application running some expensive equipment; this application dies in a variety of creative ways. Usually when it goes, the process dies completely. I wrote a little monitoring program which looks for the process' name in the list of things which are currently running, and that works great for those failures. But sometimes it just becomes completely nonresponsive and requires termination via the task manager, but is still "running" in some unhelpful sense.

I'm completely unfamiliar with the Windows API, so this is perhaps quite a stretch, but is there anything I can do to programmatically check the "liveness" of other processes? Or which I might use to make guesses? (Watching for it to stop processing events from the OS, or for all disk access/memory allocation to halt, etc, etc)

Preferably it would be something I could do via the Python win32 module, but I'll branch out to anything that can successfully detect when this thing locks up. And, I realize "liveness" is vague, but I don't want to rule anything out, particularly when I don't have any insight into how this thing is really failing.

Comment: expensive equipment?? What exactly is that? I also think you should address your problem from the inside and not from the outside.

Comment: If that were an option, that would be great, and I would pursue it. That isn't an option. This is a completely reasonable problem, as the world is full of closed source software running important machines.

I don't really care to go into details about the exact piece of software or machine because there is no upside for me. The tiny risk that the manufacturer might get grumpy about complaints is just not worth satisfying your curiosity. I only mentioned the equipment to motivate my desire for an answer, and to stave off suggestions of "just use something different".

Comment: I think the solution varies depending on what exactly is hanging. If it's a window then SecurityMatt's suggestion sounds good. Otherwise, I think you'll just have to 'inspect' the app to find some sort of notification that the app sends out saying "I'm alive" or "I'm about to hang." Unless a thread has been explicitly suspended, there isn't any sort of flag I know of that tells you the thread's hung (e.g. in an infinite loop).

Comment: @JayKominek Wait a moment, you said "sometimes it just becomes completely nonresponsive", is that the windows application or your monitoring program? If it's the application, what do you really want to do at this point? find out whether it's still alive or restart the process?

Comment: The application becomes nonresponsive. The monitoring program thinks the application is still going. What I really want is to find out when the program isn't doing anything anymore, so I can notify a live person. (Automatically restarting the application doesn't work very well.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the best way to go about this is by using the [Process & Thread functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684847%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in the WIN32 API. NB: You can easily embed C++ code in python. This will likely require some time and patience, and I do not know most of these functions myself.

On the other hand, there is a detailed project on [Process Monitoring](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38438/Monitoring-Process-Statistics-in-C-WPF) on Codeproject and [Python WMI](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/wmi/tutorial.html), a wrapper for WMI in python, but remember WMI is considerably slow and you have to ensure the service is running on the PC.

It's also possible that you might be able to [send a message to the process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that will cause the process to provide a reply or change it's state if it is alive, and then check for this change in the process for some time.

Comment: Also check [NtQueryInformationThread function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684283(v=vs.85).aspx) and [GetThreadPendingIoFlag Function.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683234(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Sending a message with SendMessageTimeout seems to be detecting at least the most common forms of freezing we were encountering.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to get a HWND handle to the window in question (EnumWindowHandles might be a good start), and then try calling IsHungAppWindow to see if the system thinks it's unresponsive.